Code doesn't compile, trying to do aim trainer
`

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    int time;
    int hitsLeft;
    int maxWidth;
    int maxHeight;
    TextView timeTextView;
    TextView hitsTextView;
    TextView TextViewToHit;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        time = 10;
        hitsLeft = 5;

        button = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        timeTextView = findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        hitsTextView = findViewById(R.id.hitsTextView);

        TextViewToHit = new TextView(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(TextViewToHit);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                countdown();
                generate();
            }
        });

        TextViewToHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (hitsLeft > 0) {
                    generate();
                    hitsLeft--;
                    hitsTextView.setText("Left hit:" + hitsLeft);
                } else {
                    hitsTextView.setText("Left hit:" + hitsLeft);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Congrats!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    restart();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void generate() {
        if (hitsLeft != 0) {
            TextViewToHit.setText("     ");
            TextViewToHit.setTextSize(70);
            TextViewToHit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
            TextViewToHit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             poza ekran, zmienic jesli dalej to robi

            maxHeight = relativeLayout.getHeight() - TextViewToHit.getHeight() - 70;
            maxWidth = relativeLayout.getWidth() - TextViewToHit.getWidth() - 70;

            Random random = new Random();

            int x = random.nextInt(maxWidth);
            int y = random.nextInt(maxHeight);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            layoutParams.leftMargin = x;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y;

            TextViewToHit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            hitsTextView.setText("Left hit:" + hitsLeft);
        }
    }
    private void restart() {
        relativeLayout.removeView(TextViewToHit);
        time = 10;
        hitsLeft = 5;
        hitsTextView.setText("Left hit:" + hitsLeft);
        timeTextView.setText("Time: "+ time);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void countdown() {
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeTextView.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                timeTextView.setText("Time: 0");
                relativeLayout.removeView(TextViewToHit);
                if (hitsLeft != 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You failed, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    restart();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}



it doesn't compile, i don't know if im missing something or something in syntax, trying to do a aim trainer application for android studio.
Here's a description of the provided code in English:
This code represents an Android application for an aim trainer game developed in Java. Below are the key components and functionalities of the code:
Activity Setup: The MainActivity class extends AppCompatActivity and handles the main functionality of the application.
Layout Initialization: The onCreate() method initializes the layout of the main activity by setting the content view to activity_main.xml. It also initializes various UI components such as buttons, text views, and the layout container.
Game Initialization: It sets initial values for the game parameters like time and hits left.
Button Click Listener: The start button's click listener triggers the game by hiding the button, starting a countdown, and generating the target.
Target Generation: The generate() method creates a target (represented by a TextView) at random positions within the layout. It updates the hits left counter and displays the remaining hits.
Target Click Listener: A click listener is attached to the target TextView. When clicked, it generates a new target, decrements the hits left, and updates the hits left counter. If no hits are left, it displays a congratulations message and restarts the game.
Restart Method: The restart() method resets the game parameters, removes the target TextView, and makes the start button visible again.
Countdown Timer: The countdown() method starts a countdown timer for the game duration. It updates the time remaining text view every second. When the time is up, it removes the target TextView and checks if there are any hits left. If not, it displays a failure message and restarts the game.
Overall, this code sets up a simple aim trainer game where the player has a limited time to hit targets that appear randomly on the screen. The game keeps track of hits remaining and provides feedback upon completion or failure.

Your problem is not exactly clear, what have you tried and it did not work for you ? have you tried to Run the code or Build your project..etc. Also, if you got any errors you should include them in your question.

The code is not being compiled maybe because of some error in naming, try referring to the naming conventions. If still doesn't work you try and append the below code and try if it works for you.
public static void main(String[] args) {
  generate();
}


Looks like you have an uncommented section in generate() method. Comment the below section poza ekran, zmienic jesli dalej to robi
It will be easier if you can share the compilation error.
